# why use div.classname instead of just .classname

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why use div.classname instead of just .classname

```
.classname{
   color: red;
}
div.classname{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: because there may be span.classname and p.classname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A higher specificity means a higher priority

i.e. the properties of div.classname{} would override properties specified in .classname{} and target only Div elements